# React Native Stack Navigation not working

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-native-navigation

I am building a fitness app, and currently I am having a problem with React Native navigation stack, that I wasn't having before and not sure why this is happening.

As you can see in the video, after you select the type of training and number of days, it should go to the screen with the filtered workouts (WorkoutSelection).

Edit: I tried moving the navigation.navigate() outside the async function and it does navigate to the correct page, so I'm assuming it has something to do with it being inside a async function.

Here's the code for the confirm button:

```
  async function confirmHandler() {
    setIsLoading(true);
    try {
      const data = await getTrainingData(
        selectedTrainingData.value,
        selectedDaysData.value
      );
      setFilteredWorkouts(data);
      setIsLoading(false);
      navigation.navigate('WorkoutSelection');
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
      setIsLoading(false);
      return (
        <ErrorScreen message={'Something went wrong. Please try again.'} />
      );
    }
  }
```

What is happening right now is whenever I click the confirm button, it goes to the home screen.

It does fetch the data from the API, I logged it to the console and it's working so, that shouldn't be the problem.

Here's the navigation code:

```
  function TrainingOptionsStack() {
    return (
      <Stack.Navigator
        screenOptions={{
          headerStyle: { backgroundColor: GlobalStyles.colors.background },
          headerTintColor: 'white',
          headerTitleStyle: {
            fontFamily: 'open-sans-semi-bold',
          },
        }}
      >
        <Stack.Screen
          name='WorkoutsScreen'
          component={WorkoutsScreen}
          options={{ title: 'Workouts' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name='SelectPhase'
          component={BlockOptions}
          options={{ title: 'Training Phase' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name='WorkoutSelection'
          component={WorkoutSelection}
          options={{
            title: 'Select a workout',
          }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen
          name='SelectDay'
          component={SelectDay}
          options={{ title: 'Select Day' }}
        />
        <Stack.Screen name='WorkoutOfTheDay' component={WorkoutOfTheDay} />

        <Stack.Screen
          name='PreviewModal'
          component={PreviewModal}
          options={{ presentation: 'modal', title: false }}
        />
      </Stack.Navigator>
    );
  }

  function AppNavigation() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Tab.Navigator
          screenOptions={{
            headerStyle: { backgroundColor: GlobalStyles.colors.background },
            headerTintColor: 'white',
            tabBarStyle: {
              backgroundColor: GlobalStyles.colors.primary700,
              paddingTop: 5,
              height: 90,
            },
            headerTitleStyle: {
              fontFamily: 'open-sans-semi-bold',
            },

            tabBarActiveTintColor: 'white',
          }}
        >
          <Tab.Screen
            name='Home'
            component={HomeScreen}
            options={{
              title: 'Home',
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                return (
                  <Ionicons
                    name='home-outline'
                    size={34}
                    color={
                      focused
                        ? GlobalStyles.colors.primary400
                        : GlobalStyles.colors.primary500
                    }
                  />
                );
              },
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name='Workouts'
            component={TrainingOptionsStack}
            options={{
              title: 'Workouts',
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                return (
                  <Ionicons
                    name='barbell-outline'
                    size={34}
                    color={
                      focused
                        ? GlobalStyles.colors.primary400
                        : GlobalStyles.colors.primary500
                    }
                  />
                );
              },
              headerShown: false,
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name='RepMaxCalculator'
            component={RepMaxCalculator}
            options={{
              title: 'Max Rep Calculator',
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                return (
                  <Ionicons
                    name='calculator-outline'
                    size={30}
                    color={
                      focused
                        ? GlobalStyles.colors.primary400
                        : GlobalStyles.colors.primary500
                    }
                  />
                );
              },
            }}
          />
          <Tab.Screen
            name='ProgressChart'
            component={ProgressChart}
            options={{
              title: 'Progress Chart',
              tabBarIcon: ({ focused }) => {
                return (
                  <Ionicons
                    name='bar-chart-outline'
                    size={30}
                    color={
                      focused
                        ? GlobalStyles.colors.primary400
                        : GlobalStyles.colors.primary500
                    }
                  />
                );
              },
            }}
          />
        </Tab.Navigator>
      </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
```

And here's the 'WorkoutSelection' component -

```
import React, { useEffect } from 'react';
import { FlatList, StyleSheet, View } from 'react-native';
import SelectWorkout from '../components/SelectWorkout';
import FlatButton from '../components/UI/buttons/FlatButton';
import { GlobalStyles } from '../constants/styles';
import useAppContext from '../store/AppContext';
import { doc, setDoc, serverTimestamp } from 'firebase/firestore';
import { db } from '../firebase/firebaseConfig';

function WorkoutSelection({ navigation }) {
  const {
    filteredWorkouts,
    previewWorkoutHandler,
    setWorkoutPreviewTitle,
    setCurrentWorkout,
    currentWorkout,
    userIsAuthenticated,
  } = useAppContext();

  // useEffect(() => {
  //   const docRef = doc(db, 'users', userIsAuthenticated.uid);
  //   async function addCurrentWorkoutToDataBase() {
  //     await setDoc(docRef, 'CurrentWorkout', currentWorkout, { merge: true });
  //   }
  //   addCurrentWorkoutToDataBase();
  // }, [currentWorkout]);

  useEffect(() => {
    navigation.setOptions({
      headerRight: () => (
        <FlatButton
          style={styles.headerButton}
          onPress={() => navigation.replace('WorkoutsScreen')}
        >
          Cancel
        </FlatButton>
      ),
    });
  }, []);

  const id = filteredWorkouts
    .flatMap((item) => item.workouts)
    .flatMap((item) => item.id);

  function previewHandler(item) {
    previewWorkoutHandler(id[0]);
    setWorkoutPreviewTitle(item.title);
    navigation.navigate('PreviewModal');
  }

  function selectWorkoutHandler(item) {
    setCurrentWorkout([item]);
    navigation.navigate('WorkoutsScreen');
  }

  return (
    <View style={styles.rootContainer}>
      <FlatList
        data={filteredWorkouts}
        renderItem={({ item }) => (
          <SelectWorkout
            name={item.title}
            onSelect={() => selectWorkoutHandler(item)}
            onShowPreview={() => previewHandler(item)}
          />
        )}
        keyExtractor={(item) => item.id}
      />
    </View>
  );
}

export default WorkoutSelection;

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  rootContainer: {
    backgroundColor: GlobalStyles.colors.background,
    flex: 1,
  },
  headerButton: {
    textDecorationLine: 'none',
    marginRight: 24,
    fontSize: 16,
    fontFamily: 'open-sans-semi-bold',
  },
});
```

Here's a little video to demonstrate the problem -
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1OoKlj2tZsL6sYqpcUnKUcQhAjmhTZGJZ/view?usp=share_link

What I expect is to go to the 'WorkoutSelection" screen so the user can complete the workout selection flow and I can update it in Firebase.

Appreciate any help!

Comment: Can you add your `WorkoutSelection` component to the question?

Comment: Hey just added the code for that component in the question.

Answer (score 0):

Have you import all the component on above page?

e.g. if you want to use `WorkoutSelection` component then import that.

like this.
import {WorkoutSelection} from 'path here'.

and then use that component for the navigation.

Hope you got my point.

Comment: The 'WorkoutSelection' is what is registered as a screen in the app component, it is imported into that component, yes. I don't see any problems, it was working before. I've tested it before adding Firestore code to the app but that shouldn't be the problem because nothing else was changed.

Answer (score 0):

It is happening because you are using `replace` function instead of `goBack` or `navigate` in `WorkoutSelection`

So first change from `replace` to `goBack` or `navigate`

after selecting values `WorkoutSelection` , if you want to refresh `WorkoutsScreen` so your selected filter can be apply then you have two ways to do that

1. call api on focus change in `WorkoutsScreen` (follow below mentioned link )
   https://reactnavigation.org/docs/function-after-focusing-screen/
2. fire event from `WorkoutSelection` before calling `goBack` or `navigate` and that event should be listened on `WorkoutsScreen` so when you get event , you can call api and refresh screen as per filter selection

Comment: I don't think that is the problem. The flow here is the user filter the workouts with the parameters - click the confirm button and then navigates to the workout selection screen, from there they can choose a workout or preview it - after selecting the desired workout, it should return to the workouts screen with the selected data. It was working fine before, for some reason it's just not working anymore and I can't figure out why.

Comment: okay let me confirm here the flow by component names.
when user tap on second tab , WorkoutsScreen is showing.
when user tap on Create Workout button that time you are navigating to WorkoutSelection where user select option and tap on confirm.
Now when user tap on confirm , you are redirecting user WorkoutsScreen screen but unfortunately it is redirecting to home screen .. is it ?

Comment: This is how it goes - 
User clicks on button create workout -> is redirected to SelectPhase, after selecting options, clicks confirm -> is redirected to 'WorkoutSelection', where all available workouts a displayed, in there you have 2 option -> Preview workout to go to the 'PreviewModal' or -> Select, which will add the selected workout to the currentWorkout state, redirect to the 'WorkoutsScreen' and be displayed in the 'WorkoutsScreen' next time user logs in.

But, instead of going to the WorkoutSelection screen, it goes back to the Home screen which not relateted.

I hope it's clear.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the problem. I had to go back a few commits and start adding one thing at a time to try to get to the point where I was having the same problem.

The problem was in the App.js, the rootFunction that I created wasn't returning anything conditionally as I wanted. I had to restructure it a bit and got it working.

Totally missed it. Thanks all for the help!

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).